# How do I pass an automatic variable to the shell in a makefile?

Tags: shell, variables, makefile, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a conditional compilation rule. If the source file contains two consecutive dollar signs, I want an extra step (latexMathToWeb below) to be performed. The problem is that the automatic variable $< is not being passed to the shell (so the grep wants to read from stdin). Here's my rule so far:

```
%.xml   : %.q
ifeq ($(shell grep \\$$\\$$ $< ; echo $$?),0)
    echo building math containing xml for $*...
    quiz2xml $< | latexMathToWeb > $@
else
    echo building non math xml for $*...
    quiz2xml $< > $@
endif
```

I currently have this problem solved by using a simple shell script to make the decision and do the build, but it would be nicer if I can do it all in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You have your contexts and timing confused here.

You are attempting to use the make parse-time constructs `ifeq` and `$(shell)` to do recipe execution time operations. You can't do that.

Move the entire test/conditional to the shell using normal shell `if` statements instead.

```
%.xml   : %.q
        if grep \\$$\\$$ $<; then \
            echo building math containing xml for $*...; \
            quiz2xml $< | latexMathToWeb > $@; \
        else \
            echo building non math xml for $*...; \
            quiz2xml $< > $@; \
        fi
```

Comment: The lack of line continuations threw me for a few seconds, but I figured it out from your original answer. Thanks so much! Seems obvious now.

Comment: Apologies for blowing that originally. Glad you got it working. That confusion happens a lot. I answered another question about that (different circumstances though) just the other day in fact.

Comment: Maybe this is not the right place to ask (I'm new to stackoverflow, as you can tell), but why would you ever use the parse-time construct ifeq (for example) if you can just hand off conditionals to the shell at runtime? No need for line continuations, maybe?

Comment: If you can do the test once at parse-time and the recipe runs hundreds (or thousands) of times during the build that will save quite a lot of work. That being said it is most often useful outside of recipes around general make constructs/assignments I think.